# Bottom bar gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Using iOS SEß 1.2.2.200.

Go to "more" section in the bottom bar, go to "my profile", go to "all post made by this user (all *[number]* posts), and tap "cancel".

Poof! The bottom bar is gone!

[image: !]

becomes:

[image: !]

Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  Previously when you tapped the cancel button on that screen it had the dual effect of popping the search page and deactivating the search controller on that screen causing an undesired animation where the search field slid up and the search results disappeared. (You can see this in the app store release 1.2.2.)  I had fixed this by not disabling the search field on "Cancel" but this resulted in the tab bar not getting restored.

Incidentally there has always been a bug where if you go from an active search field in Tags or Users to the next screen, the tab bar would not be visible but it would be accounted for in where iOS placed the scroll edge.

To fix this, I added logic so that when the view controller disappears and the search bar is active it will restore the previous tab bar hidden value.  This is symmetric with a call that already existed to hide the tab bar if active when appearing.